# Angular 6 and bootstrap 4: date picker current date selection

Tags: datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I have a form which contain a date picker and it works as expected except the current date is not selected.

**When I open the calendar it shows as follows**

[image]

**But I need the current date focused when ever I open the .date picker as follows**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `customTodayClass` to the `bsConfig` and use css to change the background color of the date.

```
<input type="text"
    placeholder="Datepicker"
    class="form-control"
    bsDatepicker
    [bsConfig]="{'customTodayClass': 'today'}"
 />
```

Add CSS for `today` class like below.

```
.today{
  background-color: #DCDCDC
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this but no change in UI. Do i need to add bsconfig in component or adding in html is enough

Comment: First check if "today" class is added to the DOM for the current date. Check also if CSS is overwritten by another class.

Comment: I have tried but it's not getting reflected, I have tried this in the following sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-j91pcq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You are using the older version(1.9.3) of ngx-bootstrap. Update the package to use "customTodayClass" config.

Comment: Thanks it worked as expected but if i select any other date, current date is still highlighted with the newly selected date

Comment: Once the user selects the date, remove `{'customTodayClass': 'today'}` option from the bsConfig

Comment: Thanks. I have done it. It helped to save lot of time